# Javascript inserting data into HTML table

Tags: javascript, html

This is a rather simple question, I am having problems inserting data from Javascript into an HTML table.

Here is an excerpt of my JavaScript:

UPDATED - I got rid of the two loops and simplified it into one, however there is still a problem..

```
    for (index = 0; index < enteredStrings.length; index++) {
        output.innerHTML += "<td>" + enteredStrings[index] + "</td>"
        + "<td>" + enteredStringsTwo[index] + "</td>";
        nameCounter++;
        total.innerHTML = "Total: " + nameCounter;
    }
```

And here is an except of my HTML page:

```
<table id="nameTable">
   <tr>
     <th>First</th><th>Last</th>
   </tr>
```

Updated Picture:

[image]

Comment: Why do you have 2 loops? What's the difference between them?

Comment: Fixed but there's still a problem.

Comment: check edit2 in my answer and see if that works for you.

Comment: Sent you an email at your Gmail address. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Updated my answer with the code that works (after seeing the actual code that is sent through email)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this (edited):

```
var tableContent = '<tr>';
for (index = 0; index < enteredStrings.length; index++) {
    tableContent += "<td>" + enteredStrings[index] + "</td>";
    nameCounter++;  // I don't know if this should be there, 
                    // logically the counter should be incremented here as well?
    total.innerHTML = "Total: " + nameCounter;
}
tableContent += '</tr><tr>';

for (index = 0; index < enteredStringsTwo.length; index++) {
    tableContent += "<td>" + enteredStringsTwo[index] + "</td>";
    nameCounter++;
    total.innerHTML = "Total: " + nameCounter;
}
tableContent += '</tr>';
output.innerHTML += tableContent;
```

**Edit2 (for updated question code):**

```
var tableContent = '<tr>';
for (index = 0; index < enteredStrings.length; index++) {
    tableContent += "<td>" + enteredStrings[index] + "</td>"
    + "<td>" + enteredStringsTwo[index] + "</td>";
    nameCounter++;
    total.innerHTML = "Total: " + nameCounter;
}
tableContent += '</tr>';
output.innerHTML += tableContent;
```

**Edit3 (after looking at the code sent in email):**

```
var tableContent = "";

for (index = 0; index < enteredStrings.length; index++) {
    tableContent += "<tr><td>" + enteredStrings[index] + "</td>"

    + "<td>" + enteredStringsTwo[index] + "</td></tr>";

    nameCounter++;
    total.innerHTML = "Total: " + nameCounter;
}
output.innerHTML = tableContent;
```

Comment: it wont help since the browser creates the <tr> automatically since you are updating the innerHTML every time.

Comment: @The Scrum Meister: sorry, I didn't get what you are saying. I don't see anything logically wrong with my code.

Comment: since output is a element, upon each call to output.innerHTML the browser will fix the html to be proper. so the first call is adding a open <tr> only, however the broswer will **close** that tr for you. same applies for the next change which appends the td.

Comment: @The Scrum Meister: I didn't know that, edited my answer to take care of that then. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

instead of closing the td you are opening new ones
try

```
    for (index = 0; index < enteredStrings.length; index++) {
    output.innerHTML += "<td>" + enteredStrings[index] + "</td>";
    total.innerHTML = "Total: " + nameCounter;
}

for (index = 0; index < enteredStringsTwo.length; index++) {
    output.innerHTML += "<td>" + enteredStringsTwo[index] + "</td>";
    nameCounter++;
    total.innerHTML = "Total: " + nameCounter;
}
```

UPDATE:
you are **appending** the html to the **table** instead of the **row**.
in this case, the browser created a row for you automatically after the each td is appended.

Comment: what is the output pointing to? the table or the table row? what browser are you using?

Comment: output = document.getElementById('nameTable'); and I'm using Firefox.

Comment: your output should point to <tr> tag of nameTable instead of table itself

Answer (score 0):

With slight modifications in your code,

```
    var outputTbl = document.getElementById('nameTable');

    var output = document.createElement("tr");
    outputTbl.appendChild(output);

    for (index = 0; index < enteredStrings.length; index++) {
        output.innerHTML += "<td>" + enteredStrings[index] + "</td>";
        total.innerHTML = "Total: " + nameCounter;
    }

    for (index = 0; index < enteredStringsTwo.length; index++) {
       output.innerHTML += "<td>" + enteredStringsTwo[index] + "</td>";
       nameCounter++;
       total.innerHTML = "Total: " + nameCounter;
    }
```

Comment: That appears to work however when I attempt to enter a second name it recreates another table. As show in this image. http://i54.tinypic.com/244dszr.jpg

Answer (score -1):

If you need to add inner html code here.

```
<table id="nameTable" style="width:300px;">
    <tr>
        <th>First</th><th>Last</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can use [Jnerator](http://jnerator.com) in this case.

If this is your data:

```
var data = [
    { first: 'Cole', last: 'Alan'},
    { first: 'Michael', last: 'Scott'}
]
```

You can add them to you table in next way:

```
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var item = data[i];
    var row = $j.tr({ child:[$j.td(item.first), $j.td(item.last)] });
    nameTable.appendChild(row.dom());
}
nameTotal.innerHTML = 'Total: ' + data.length;
```

[This is example](http://jsfiddle.net/jnerator/m4r8n/).